# Finding my upvotes or downvotes that are questions (or answers)

Tags: support

Just as by entering the command
deleted:1 is:a
deleted:2 is:q
yields  one's  postings (answers or questions)  that had been deleted, is there a similar way (command) to quickly list one's votes (upvotes or downvotes) for postings that are questions or answers?

Perhaps there is a SQL query that may do this. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If you're looking to find votes you cast, you can do that on your main profile page. Click on your user icon on the top bar, then click on "activity" in the row beneath your profile picture, then click on "votes" which will be at the bottom of the left column, beneath "responses".

Comment: @KReiser: I know that, however, there is no easy way to determine whether they are questions or answers and one has to go by post by post. I am trying to rid of many downvotes I have cast for answers only that might have been edited and/or corrected.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure how to do that via search or sql then. Best of luck.